# Force layout inside force layout: How to drag inner nodes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm working on an application with a force layout on large circles.  To each node in that force layout, I attach another force layout on smaller circles, which appear inside the large circles ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mars0i/s6y183mh/2/)).

D3.js's force layout allows one drag nodes with the mouse. However, although the smaller, inner circles move in relation to the larger, outer circles because of the inner force layouts, I've unable to drag the inner circles in any way that seems independent of the larger circles.  That is, dragging an inner circle is exactly like dragging the outer circle.  (Setting the `fixed` property of the data attached to the outer node doesn't help--as in [this slightly more complicated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mars0i/toywvbLz/3/).)

Is it possible to allow the inner circles to be dragged within the larger circles?  Allowing the inner circles to be dragged independently of the outer circle--even past its edge--would be very acceptable behavior, too, although not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you drag the inner circle, you are also dispatching `drag` events to the outer nodes (because they are overlapped). To prevent this, you need to use `d3.event.stopPropagation()` for your drag behviour.

```
var innerAnodes = aNode.selectAll("g.inner")
  .data(innerAdata, function (d) {return d.id;})
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "inner")
  .attr("id", function (d) {return d.id;})
  .call(innerAlayout.drag()
        .on("dragstart", function(){            
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        })
       );
```

Here is your [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/s6y183mh/4/).

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  I had no idea that you could chain `on` directly on `drag`, and wouldn't have thought of, or known the proper way to use `stopPropagation` for this purpose.  I was unaware of `sourceEvent`, etc.  Mouse handling is still a fuzzy area for me.